# encoding - accentuation with form in HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, encoding

I'm an accent problem with a form inserted in html form. I've tried every way to use all that is within reach of a good search on google, but I could not solve the problem. For the characters keep coming crazy way.

Email: root@example.com

Nome: RaÃ§Ã£o

ComentÃ¡rio: RaÃ§Ã£o

**Follow the scripts below.**

**HTML**

```
                <form class="form-inline" role="form" method=post  accept-charset="UTF-8" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>

                    <input type=email class="form-control transparent" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required > 

                    <input type=text class="form-control transparent" name="Nome" size=25 placeholder="Nome" required >

                    <input type=text class="form-control transparent" name="WhatsApp" size=25 placeholder="WhatsApp: Ex: 11 - 8888 - 9999 "  > 

                    <textarea  rows=4 cols=30 class="form-control transparent" name="Comentário" placeholder="Sua linda mensagem, aqui ♥" required></textarea>

                    <div style="color: #fff; font-size: 12px; margin-bottom: 30px; margin: 0 auto 30px; text-align: center;">
                      <input type="radio" name="AntiSpam" required /> ← Marque antes de enviar </div></div>

<button class="btn btn-danger btn-fill" type="submit" >Enviar</button></form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>$('.form-inline').attr('action', 'mail.php');</script>
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$sendFrom =    "Contato TopMágico <contato@topmagico.com.br>";

$sendTo =      "foo@gmail.com";

$subjectLine = "Contato TopMágico";

$thanksURL =   "gratidao.php";   

foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value)
   $msgBody .= "$field: $value\n";

$msgBody .= "\n" . @gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) . "\n" . $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

$msgBody = htmlspecialchars($msgBody, ENT_NOQUOTES);  //make safe
$spam = count($_POST) == 0 || stristr($msgBody, "cc: ") ||
          stristr($msgBody, "href=") || stristr($msgBody, "[url");

      if (!$spam)
          mail($sendTo, $subjectLine, $msgBody, "From: $sendFrom"); 
header("Location: $thanksURL");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding/changing your meta charset to UTF8 on your HTML file

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

If that doesnt work, change it to

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
```

Comment: try changing you PHP `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1`